# Why is my date input field in AngularJS throwing type error?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The error occurs when I display the populated, editable form to the user (not when a user enters in data and submits).  The data is coming from MySQL over REST/JSON in the service shown below:

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="dateInput" id="dateOfBirth" 
                   ng-model="user.dateOfBirth">
```

CCONTROLLER:

```
.controller('EditCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, UserDetail, $window) {
        $scope.user = UserDetail.find({}, {'id': $routeParams.id});
}
```

SERVICE:

```
service.factory('UserDetail', function ($resource) {

    return $resource(
        'http://localhost:8080/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
    {
    find: {method: 'GET'},

    });
});
```

ERROR:

Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2010-05-13T00:00:00-04:00` to be a date

Comment: the input value is a string, not a date. you can call new Date(input.value) to get a real date object.

Comment: In the controller? Tried that and it seems to get overwritten ... Perhaps when a promise returns from service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because that is not a valid date according to Angular. [Check out the doc on input[date]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) for their note on date validation. For it to be a date it should be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @vt97john This sounds like a separate question. You should write up a new one and include more of your code so that we can see what is going on with it.

Comment: I added more code to the above.  Where / how can I properly format the date?

Comment: I finally got it working.  My original attempt to format failed because it was overwritten after a promise returned from a service call.  I had to do the formatting using a "transformResponse" on the service ($resource) response to get it to work.                                                                  find: {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
                data.dateOfBirth = new Date(data.dateOfBirth);
                return data;
            }
        }

Answer (score 13):

AngularJS 1.3 adds to input [date | datetime-local ] fields a new formatter/parser that checks that the model is a Date Object and throw the datefmt exception.

```
if (value && !isDate(value)) {
    throw $ngModelMinErr('datefmt', 'Expected `{0}` to be a date', value);
```

This issue is not present at previos versions and I suggest get in consideration on upgrade to avoid big nightmares.

A workaroud is to reset default formatters/parser with a custom dateFormat directive and use momentjs to format,parse strings to Date.

```
define(['directives/directives','momentjs'], function(directives,momentjs) {
directives.directive('dateFormat', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
          var format=attr.dateFormat;
          //Angular 1.3 insert a formater that force to set model to date object, otherwise throw exception.
          //Reset default angular formatters/parsers
          ngModelCtrl.$formatters.length=0;
          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.length=0;

          ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(valueFromModel) {
             //return how data will be shown in input
              if(valueFromModel){
                 // For momentjs > 2.9 moment global va is not defined use momentjs instead of moment.
                  return moment(valueFromModel).format(format);
              }
              else
                  return null;
          });
          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(valueFromInput) {
              if(valueFromInput){
                  //For momentjs > 2.9 moment global va is not defined use momentjs instead of moment.
                  return moment(valueFromInput,format).toDate();
              }
              else 
                  return null;
          });
        }
      };
    });
});
```

**UPDATE** With momentjs > 2.9 take in consideration that the moment global var are not defined.

```
2.9 "Deprecation warning: Accessing Moment through the global scope is deprecated, and will be removed in an upcoming release."
```

With AMD need use `momentjs` instead of `moment`. i.e:

```
return momentjs(valueFromModel).format(format);
```

Comment: After wasting whole day, finally, this solution works!! 

For input type datetime-local, I used date-format="YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm" and got it working on Ionic app.

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

In your api

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$new_date = date("c",strtotime($date));
echo json_encode(array("date"=>$new_date));
```

In your controller

```
/* var date 
* this is value from your api
*/
$scope.date = new Date(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

For date value in an array one can use this as:

```
    var dates = [
      { id: "1" , date: "2015-04-20T11:24:20.882Z"},
      { id: "2" , date: "2015-05-20T11:24:20.882Z"},
      { id: "3" , date: "2015-06-20T11:24:20.882Z"},
    ];

      function dateStringToObject (data) {
        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){
          data[i].date = new Date(data[i].date);
          }

        return data;
      }

   dateStringToObject(dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically its not about the format, it want a valid new Date() object in ISO format ,so whatever you get response ,just do a new Date and angular will be happy , i got this when i parsed the exception message caused by angular

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2015-11-24